# Angular 2 Native i18n: select option does not support the `null` or default case for a value

Tags: angular, internationalization

While using angular i18n native, I have trouble getting the translation for a null value in a `select`. Example:

```
<md-option *ngFor="let s of salutations" [value]="s.value" i18n>
    { s.value, select, null{--Select--} mr{Mr.} mrs{Mrs.} miss{Miss} }
</md-option>
```

In the example above '--Select--' does not get translated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "other" keyword in your select in order to handle null values.

```
<md-option *ngFor="let s of salutations" [value]="s.value" i18n>
     { s.value, select, mr{Mr.} mrs{Mrs.} miss{Miss} other{--Select--} }
</md-option>
```

See the complete formatting here : http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages